# Ejecutar script de búsqueda al presionar enter

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php 
/*if(!function_exists('olomo_search_filter_init')){
    function olomo_search_filter_js(){
        wp_register_script('bootstrap-slider', site_url() .'/wp-content/plugins/olomo-search-filter/assets/js/bootstrap-slider.min.js'); 
        wp_register_script('search-filter-setting', site_url() .'/wp-content/plugins/olomo-
        -filter/assets/js/settings.js'); 
        wp_enqueue_script('
        -filter-setting');
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-slider');

    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'olomo_search_filter_js');*/

function olomo_search_filter_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( '
    -style');
    wp_enqueue_style( '
    -style', site_url() .'/wp-content/plugins/olomo-search-filter/assets/css/style.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'olomo_search_filter_css' );
function search_filter_form ()
{
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
    jQuery( function() {
        jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 10000,
            values: [ 0, 10000 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                jQuery( "#amount" ).val(  'Price Range ($): ' + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                jQuery( "#amounts" ).val(  ui.values[ 0 ] + "," + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        });
        jQuery( "#amount" ).val(  'Price Range ($): ' + jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - " + jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
            jQuery( "#amounts" ).val(  jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            "," + jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    } );

      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    jQuery("#autocomplete").autocomplete({ 
                        source:'<?php echo site_url();?>/wp-content/plugins/olomo-search-filter/include/ajax-post-autocomplete.php', 
                        minLength:1
                    });

                     jQuery("#autocompletetag").autocomplete({ 
                        source:'<?php echo site_url();?>/wp-content/plugins/olomo-search-filter/include/ajax-tag-autocomplete.php',
                        minLength:1
                    });

        });
</script>
<style>
.ui-draggable, .ui-droppable {
    background-position: top;
}
</style>
<?php

    global $olomo_options;  
    $show_categories = get_option( 'show_categories' );
    $show_locations = get_option( 'show_locations' );
    $show_price = get_option( 'show_price' );
    $show_status = get_option( 'show_status' );
    $show_address = get_option( 'show_address' );
    $show_rating = get_option( 'show_rating' );

    $ucat = array(

                     'post_type' => 'listing',

                      'hide_empty' => false,

                      'orderby' => 'count',

                      'order' => 'ASC',

                      'parent'=> 0,

                    );

                    $categories = get_terms( 'listing-category',$ucat);
                    $locations = get_terms( 'location',$ucat);


?>
<div id="filter_form2">
  <div class="main_bg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="advanced-filter-m">
          <form action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/resultado-busqueda/" method="get">
            <?php if($show_categories == 'yes') { ?>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
              <div class="select">
                <select class="form-control" name="category">
                  <option value="">Elegir Categoría </option>
                  <?php foreach($categories as $cat) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?> </option>
                  <?php } ?>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php } 
                 if($show_status == 'yes') { ?>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
              <div class="select">
                <select class="form-control" name="status">
                  <option value="">Seleccionar Status</option>
                  <option value="">Todos</option>
                  <option value="open">Abierto</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php }   ?>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
              <div class="select">
                <input type="text" name="search_by_title" value="" placeholder="Buscar por nombre" class="search-autocomplete" id="autocomplete">
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php if($show_address == 'yes') { ?>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
              <div class="select">
                <input type="text" name="gAddress" value="" placeholder="Buscar por dirección" id="inputAddress">
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php } 
                 if($show_price == 'yes') { ?>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; background: transparent;">
              <input type="hidden" id="amounts" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" name="priceRange">
              <div id="slider-range"></div>
            </div>
            <?php } 
             if($show_rating == 'yes') { ?>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
              <select class="form-control" name="ratingFrom" id="ratingFrom">
                <option value="">Valoración desde</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
              </select>
              <select class="form-control" name="ratingTo" id="ratingTo">
                <option value="">Valoración hasta</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <?php } 
                 if($show_locations == 'yes') { ?>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
              <div class="select">
                <select class="form-control" name="location">
                  <option value="">Elegir ubicación </option>
                  <?php foreach($locations as $loc) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $loc->name; ?>"><?php echo $loc->name; ?> </option>
                  <?php } ?>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php } 
                 if($show_locations == 'yes') { ?>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
              <div class="select">
                <input type="text" name="search_by_tags_keywords" value="" placeholder="Etiquetas o Palabras Claves" id="autocompletetag">
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block" name="search_listing"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Buscar </button>
            </div>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php   


}
add_shortcode('search-filter','search_filter_form');

function search_filter_sidebar_form ()
{
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
    jQuery( function() {
        jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 10000,
            values: [ 0, 10000 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                jQuery( "#amount" ).val(  'Price Range ($): ' + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                jQuery( "#amounts" ).val(  ui.values[ 0 ] + "," + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        });
        jQuery( "#amount" ).val(  'Price Range ($): ' + jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - " + jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
            jQuery( "#amounts" ).val(  jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            "," + jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    } );

      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    jQuery("#autocomplete").autocomplete({ 
                        source:'<?php echo site_url();?>/wp-content/plugins/olomo-search-filter/include/ajax-post-autocomplete.php', 
                        minLength:0
                    }).focus(function() {
    jQuery(this).autocomplete("search", jQuery(this).val());
});

                     jQuery("#autocompletetag").autocomplete({ 
                        source:'<?php echo site_url();?>/wp-content/plugins/olomo-search-filter/include/ajax-tag-autocomplete.php',
                        minLength:0
                    }).focus(function() {
    jQuery(this).autocomplete("search", jQuery(this).val());
});

        });
</script>
<style>
.ui-draggable, .ui-droppable {
    background-position: top;
}
</style>
<?php

    global $olomo_options;  
    $show_categories = get_option( 'show_categories' );
    $show_locations = get_option( 'show_locations' );
    $show_price = get_option( 'show_price' );
    $show_status = get_option( 'show_status' );
    $show_address = get_option( 'show_address' );
    $show_rating = get_option( 'show_rating' );

    $ucat = array(

                     'post_type' => 'listing',

                      'hide_empty' => false,

                      'orderby' => 'count',

                      'order' => 'ASC',

                      'parent'=> 0,

                    );

                    $categories = get_terms( 'listing-category',$ucat);
                    $locations = get_terms( 'location',$ucat);


?>
        <form action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/resultado-busqueda/" method="get">
         <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="select searchtitle">
              <input type="text" name="search_by_title" value="" placeholder="Buscar por nombre" class="search-autocomplete" id="autocomplete">
              <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php if($show_categories == 'yes') { ?>
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="select">
              <select class="form-control" name="category">
                <option value="">Seleccionar Categoría </option>
                <?php foreach($categories as $cat) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?> </option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php } 
             if($show_status == 'yes') { ?>
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="select">
              <select class="form-control" name="status">
                <option value="">Seleccionar Status</option>
                <option value="">Todos</option>
                <option value="open">Abierto</option>

              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php }   ?>
          <?php if($show_address == 'yes') { ?>
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="select">
              <input type="text" name="gAddress" value="" placeholder="Buscar por dirección" id="inputAddress">
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php } 
             if($show_price == 'yes') { ?>
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; background: transparent;">
            <input type="hidden" id="amounts" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" name="priceRange">
            <div id="slider-range"></div>
          </div>
          <?php } 
         if($show_rating == 'yes') { ?>
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <select class="form-control" name="ratingFrom">
              <option value="">Seleccionar Valoración desde</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <select class="form-control" name="ratingTo">
              <option value="">Seleccionar Valoración hasta</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <?php } 
             if($show_locations == 'yes') { ?>
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="select">
              <select class="form-control" name="location">
                <option value="">Seleccionar Ubicación </option>
                <?php foreach($locations as $loc) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $loc->name; ?>"><?php echo $loc->name; ?> </option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php } 
             if($show_locations == 'yes') { ?>
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="select">
              <input type="text" name="search_by_tags_keywords" value="" placeholder="Etiquetas o Palabras Claves" id="autocompletetag">
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php } ?>
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block" name="search_listing"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Buscar </button>
          </div>
        </form>
<?php   

}
add_shortcode('search-filter-sidebar','search_filter_sidebar_form');
```

Corresponde a dos filtros de búsqueda, la primera función es de un filtro que funciona en todos los escenarios, si introduzco un criterio de búsqueda y se presiona el botón de Buscar o si se presiona enter, devuelve el resultado de la búsqueda.

La segunda función igual es un filtro, pero sólo funciona si después de introducir un criterio se presiona el botón de Buscar, en caso que se presione enter no devuelve ningún resultado.

Estas son las URL de los escenarios:
Al presionar Enter:

https://yiinic.com/resultado-busqueda/?search_by_title=Pretzel+Paradise&category=&location=&search_by_tags_keywords=

Al presionar el botón de Enviar:

https://yiinic.com/resultado-busqueda/?search_by_title=Pretzel+Paradise&category=&location=&search_by_tags_keywords=&search_listing=

Creo que por ahí va la situación, pero mi nivel de PHP y javascript es básico y no he podido encontrar la solución.

Les agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda.

Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo resolví estimados, al final el problema era en el mismo código HTML:

```
<div class="select searchtitle">
   <input type="text" name="search_by_title" value="" placeholder="Buscar 
   por nombre" class="search-autocomplete" id="autocomplete">
   **<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>**
</div>
```

En este formulario, a la derecha del input hay un submit, había que agregarle el name igual que el submit del final o sea name="search_listing"

De todas formas gracias a los que se tomaron el tiempo de ver el caso.